# giving non domain user access to TFS-2018 on-premises

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

we have TFS-2018 on our in house server, now we have situation were we want to provide access to third party (external user) is there any way we can do it.

The external users IT team does not alow them to install our VPN client on there system.

what i think is

If we expose our TFS URL to internet and create a user in our domain will they be able to access our TFS from that created user in our domain for doing checkins, check-out, manage build and deploy & managing work items.

Please help me understand if what i think is right and that is possible.

or please suggest the right way to do.

Comment: Hi Did you get a chance to check out the document in below answer? how did it go?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible that external user can access your TFS with the created user account in your domain if you expose TFS url to internet.

Since your TFS URL is accessible from the external with VPN client installed, You can provision the external user a machine with the VPN client configured. And you need to create a user account in your domain for the external user. Then he will be able to access your TFS server using the user account from the provisioned machine.

Please check out below document for more information.

[Providing Internet Access to Team Foundation Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/msp-n-p/bb668967(v=pandp.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

[How to change Team Foundation Server 2010 urls for use externally](https://www.tjopsta.net/2010/04/16/how-to-change-team-foundation-server-2010-urls-for-use-externally/)